# Valid null returns and warnings in C#

Tags: c#, null, warnings

I am updating very old code to VS2022.  Some of the string extension functions return null and VS2022 flags this with a warning. What is the modern recommended or accepted method to handle this to eliminate the warnings?

As you can see in the example below, the null is returned if (and only if) the original string was null.  In some sense, this is a proper handling.  That said, should we suppress the warning in VS, but risk missing valid warnings of null returns in other places?  Or, should we change the behavior of the original code to return something else besides null, such as an empty string.  Or, we could just live with the benign warnings... but I hate left-over, benign warnings.  They are noise and can obscure real issues.

Opinions, thoughts, what is the recommended way to proceed?

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a new string with multiple, contiguous embedded spaces and tabs reduced to a single space
        /// and single embedded tabs converted to spaces
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="str"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string MultipleSpacesToOneSpace(this string str) {
            if ( str == null ) return null;
            var len = str.Length;
            var src = str.ToCharArray();
            int dstIdx = 0;
            bool lastWasWS = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var ch = src[i];
                if (src[i] == '\u0020' || src[i] == '\u0009') {  // spaces and tabs
                    if (lastWasWS == false) {
                        src[dstIdx++] = ch;
                        lastWasWS = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    lastWasWS = false;
                    src[dstIdx++] = ch;
                }
            }

            string newStr = new string(src, 0, dstIdx);
            return newStr.Replace('\u0009', '\u0020');  // replace tabs with spaces
        }
```

-Mark R.

Comment: Just to clarify, in what case should the extension method be called for a string equal to null? Doesnt that mean, that you would need to call that extension on something like `string? t = null;` and then `t.MultipleSpacesToOneSpace()`?

Comment: `return str != null ? Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ") : null;` - we just replace all contiguous *white spaces* into single space

Comment: @LeonBohmann - I'm learning already!  I see by trying your example the calling context is also flagged as possible null.  In general, as this is a library, I don't know when the extension would be called with a null string.  Maybe that's no longer an issue as it was in the ole' days?

Comment: @DmitryBrychenko - that is a very nice reduction of code using Regex, but it also has the same warning.

Comment: @mroyer I think if that method is an extension from a library, it should only be valid as such. So from my perspective, maybe you should think about for what kind of strings this should be used? The line where it returns null is only valid for nullable strings. So maybe add a second extension method for `string? input`, which has the first line from the old extension method but includes a call after that to the old method (without the null check). You know what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to [forgive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `null`s with a help of `!` operator:

```
...
if ( str == null ) return null!;
...
```

You can also simplify the implementation with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public static string MultipleSpacesToOneSpace(this string str) =>
  str != null ? Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ") : null!;
```

here we match all consequent *whitespaces* (tabs, spaces, non breaking spaces etc.) and replace them with single space. And again, we *forgive* null returning with `null!`.

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for that - so simple, yet so perfectly applicable.  I was unaware of the '!' suffix syntax.

Comment: To clarify, the question is not about the efficiency of the multiple spaces to one space code.  That is code that has existed since the start of the millennium, and I'm not sure why the author didn't use regular expressions . It is about returning a null when it is valid to do so.  There are many places in the library where this happens and the null! syntax is perfect.  I just happened to use the multiple spaces method as the example.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For further explanation of my comment and using @Dimitry Bychencko s answer you could come up with:

```
public static string? MultipleSpacesToOneSpace(this string? input){
    if (input == null) return null;
    
    return ((string)input).MultipleSpacesToOneSpace();
}
```

And then remove the first line from your original method.